# Changing the default background color (#ccccff) for .orbit-container in foundation 5

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

In Zurb Foundation 5, does anybody know how to change the default orbit container background of blue without going into app.css to change the background property for .orbit-container class?

The default code for orbit slider does not explicitly state .orbit-container, so it doesn't seem possible to change it inline.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered writing your own CSS-rule for `.orbit-container`? If you put your own stylesheet, it will override it assuming it is applied after the foundation stylesheet.

Comment: thanks I managed it. I needed to do it for that _particular_ orbit slider. I managed to do it by making a super-div for the slider's body content, gave it an ID and combined `.orbitcontainer` with the ID of the super-div in CSS, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I did it myself.

Make a super `<div>` element to include that particular section and give it an ID. Then in CSS, do

```
.orbit-container  #(Given ID)
{
 background:(arguments)
}
```

This will help you change the orbit-container background for just the particular section (marked by ID).